# React Native TypeError: undefined is not an object ('evaluating useFormikContext.errors')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I am developing an app with react native. using formik for forms, I am getting this error 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useFormikContext.errors')
[image: this is the error I am getting]'

```
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";

import { ErrorMessage } from "./index";
import ImageInputList from "../ImageInputList";

function FormImagePicker({ name }) {
  const { errors, setFieldValue, touched, values } = useFormikContext();
  const imageUris = values[name];

  const handleAdd = (uri) => {
    setFieldValue(name, [...imageUris, uri]);
  };
  const handleRemove = (uri) => {
    setFieldValue(
      name,
      imageUris.filter((imageUri) => imageUri !== uri)
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ImageInputList
        imageUris={imageUris}
        onAddImage={handleAdd}
        onRemoveImage={handleRemove}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </>
  );
}

export default FormImagePicker;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get an object property when is not defined yet, try doing this:

```
{errors && (<ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />)}
```

If this is not what you want, try to find a different solution but always remember that you can't get `errors[name]` just like that, you have to be sure that `errors` exists before doing that.

Hope this solves your problem, Cheers!

Comment: I tried it but still getting the same error, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should call `FormImagePicker` inside a formik component:

```
 <AppForm
    initialValues={{
      title: "",
      price: "",
      description: "",
      category: null,
      images: [],
    }}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
  >
    <FormImagePicker name="images" />      // ==> here <==

    <AppFormField maxLength={255} name="title" placeholder="Title" />
    
    <AppFormField
      keyboardType="numeric"
      maxLength={8}
      name="price"
      placeholder="Pirce"
      width={120}
    />
    <AppFormPicker
      item={categories}
      name="category"
      placeholder="Category"
      width={"50%"}
      PickerItemComponent={CategoryPickerItem}
      numberOfColumns={3}
    />
```